# python how to make early return when asyncio generator

Tags: python, generator, python-asyncio

I want to return the first element of async generator and handle the remainning values without return like fire and forget. How to make early return of coroutine in python?
After passing the iterator to `asyncio.create_task`, it doesn't print the remaining values.

```py
import asyncio
import time


async def async_iter(num):
    for i in range(num):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        yield i

async def handle_remains(it):
    async for i in it:
        print(i)

async def run() -> None:
    it = async_iter(10)
    async for i in it:
        print(i)
        break
    # await handle_remains(it) 
    # want to make this `fire and forget`(no await), expecting just printing the remainning values.
    asyncio.create_task(handle_remains(it))
    return i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(run())
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: You need to have an event loop that runs the task: take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks).

Comment: @Jens Isn't that what `asyncio.run()` does for you?

Comment: The [`create_task()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) function returns a [Task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) which in the example code is thrown away—i.e. not assigned and left scheduled.

Comment: @Jens Hm, from the link: _The task is executed in the loop returned by get_running_loop(), RuntimeError is raised if there is no running loop in current thread._?

Comment: @Jens Maybe I've misinterpreted the statement and it is just about in which loop the task is executed and not about the execution itself? Reads a bit ambivalent, though.

Answer (score 0):

You’re close with the code, but not quite there yet (see also my comments above). In short, creating the [Task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) isn’t enough: the Task needs to run:

```py
task = asyncio.create_task(handle_remains(it))  # Creates a Task in `pending` state.
await task  # Run the task, i.e. execute the wrapped coroutine.
```

A Task, along with coroutines and Futures, is an “[Awaitable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#awaitables)”. In fact:

> When a coroutine is wrapped into a Task with functions like asyncio.create_task() the coroutine is automatically scheduled to run soon.

Notice the “scheduled to run soon”, now you have to make sure to actually run the task by calling [await](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#await-expression), a keyword which…

> is used to obtain a result of coroutine execution.

Comment: But what if you don't want to explicitly `await` the task? E.g. in Node.js, the event loop runs until there are no more tasks to run.

Comment: @Jens I don't want to await the task. Just want to fire and forget like js event loop. But now I understand the `create_task`, Thanks!

Comment: Well, this is Python and not JavaScript — different languages, different runtimes. Would you mind sharing the JavaScript equivalent (e.g. as a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/)) of your Python example above which illustrates what you’d like to achieve here?